# Using document.Application.PixelsToPoints will give different results

Tags: c#, ms-word

When I use document.Application.PixelsToPoints(14), the parameters are the same, the environment is the same, and the same computer is used, but the results are different.

The result obtained by a.word is: 7
`var aword = document.Application.PixelsToPoints(14); //  aword = 7`
The result obtained by b.word is: 10.5
`var bword = document.Application.PixelsToPoints(14); //  bword = 10.5`

How do I manipulate these two words to get the same result?

Comment: This should be tagged as word? vba? not c#. And your question could probably use more context, what are you doing and why?

Comment: sorry,'word' requires at least 1500 reputation, I don't have more reputation, and I use c# program this project. I want to create a new style using code, and I want to set the font size.  I used the PixelsToPoints method, but it resulted in different font sizes for different words.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why the extracted values are different. If the `<w:pixelsPerInch w:val="144"/>` attribute is set in the WebSettings.xml file of Word, the result obtained will be different from the default result without this attribute